# How do I calculate the total amount per category by multiplying amounts with distinct multipliers?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I know how to program in python/go/bash, but I'm a super noob when it comes to `excel or google sheets`. Sometimes they are super helpful, but I often find it difficult to figure out what's an easy approach to solve problems.

My issue here is mostly not knowing what query to search for / how to describe my problem.

In this case, I'm trying to calculate what length of various cables I need to buy to rewire my house (coax, cat6a, etc): left axis is cable conduits, multiplier is conduit length, and top axis is cable types. This issue applies to a lot of other things I've had to deal with in the past too so I'll generalize below.

Here is an example table for the initial data/planning:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | multiplier | a | b | c | d |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 2 |  | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 20 |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 30 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 5 | 4 | 40 |  | 1 | 2 |  |

What I want to achieve is:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | n | total |
| 2 | a | 3 | `=2*10+1*30` |
| 3 | b | 2 | `=1*20+1*40` |
| 4 | c | 3 | `=1*10+2*40` |
| 5 | d | 1 | `=1*20` |

I know that transposing from `c1:f1` is my first step to creating the left axis, and I have experience using `SUMIF`, but this is more complex as it needs multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. This site already has a lot of questions about [tag:google-sheets]. Please add links to the most relevant questions and explain why they don't meet your needs.